# Что именно не так с кодом

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i, a[10], b[10];
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    printf("a[%d] = ", i);
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }
  printf("Masiv b");
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
      if (a[i]==a[i])
      {
          printf("\n b[%d] = 1", i);
      }
      else (a[i]!=a[i])
      {
        printf("\n b[%d] = 0", i);
      }
  }
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Задание]

Comment: Интересно, как вы себе представляете, когда `a[i]!=a[i]` даст `true`?...

Comment: во-первых, не ясна цель программы, во-вторых, не понятно что именно не устраивает?

Comment: В-третьих, задание хорошо бы перевести на русский.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие, то проще всего примерно так:

```
int main()
{
    int i,j, a[10], b[10] = {0};
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
            if (i != j && a[i]==a[j])
            {
                b[i] = 1;
                break;
            }
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("b[%d] = %d\n", i, b[i]);
}
```

Comment: Да все четко спасибо